# Why does a try block affect drupal_set_message?

Tags: users, database, forms

I have a try block set up:

```
try {
//some code
throw new Exception ( 'My exception message' );
}
catch ( Exception $e ) 
drupal_set_message('Caught exception: '. $e->getMessage(),1);}
```

[image]

But instead of using 'status', 'warning' or 'error' I used an integer and get a greyish looking message box. Are there any other "hidden" drupal_set_message options? Thx

Comment: The second argument of `drupal_set_message()` should be a string. This string is just added as a class around the message. It an be anything you want.

Comment: @2pha, correct, but if you leave no argument then drupal_set_message defaults to 'status'. Using an integer appears to apply a different class even though an integer is not a valid documented argument. Are there any other undocumented values or types that can be used as the second argument?

Comment: @JohnR There aren't - `drupal_set_message()` just doesn't make a check, it passes the 'type' through as a class on the element verbatim. You could even call it a feature so you can extend message types by simply applying a new class. Or you could argue it's a bug and the type should be checked against the list of allowed options, depends how you want to look at it.

Comment: @2pha You should put that in as an answer :)

Comment: @Clive Agreed!! Dang good explanation!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument of drupal_set_message() should be a string. This string is just added as a class around the message. It an be anything you want.